# Live streaming Azure framework,is url issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

- Working on ios app.

  - For live streaming.
  - Using Azure framework.

*I am receiving the bytes at run time.
But could not play them in Azure Media Player.*

In Demo app we are able to play the static url from the server.

http://nimbuspartnerorigin.cloudapp.net/8260c015-abfb-4c8d-8c3a-689b1448e279/Contoso_93d705de-fe6b-4430-b0ab-4c291665b610-m3u8-**aapl.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)**

But when we are streaming live we have to create the url like from server.

http://nimbuspartnerorigin.cloudapp.net/8260c015-abfb-4c8d-8c3a-689b1448e279/Contoso_93d705de-fe6b-4430-b0ab-4c291665b610-m3u8-**aapl.isml/Manifest**

1. Should I convert the Manifest file to .m3u8 format ?
   Any body knows how to convert that manifest file to m3u8 file format ?
   Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nimbuspartnerorigin.cloudapp.net/8260c015-abfb-4c8d-8c3a-689b1448e279/Contoso_93d705de-fe6b-4430-b0ab-4c291665b610-m3u8-aapl.isml/Manifest is a Smooth Streaming Manifest that can't be played back using Azure framework. You will need to create HLS live stream.

Comment: Means you are saying that I need to convert that file to m3u8 format.

Comment: What do u mean by smooth streaming ?

Comment: Smooth Streaming is one specific format for Adaptive Streaming and HLS (Http live streaming) is another one. Smooth streaming ends with /manifest and HLS ends with m3u8. Both of them are based on H.264 but package differently. yes, you will need a HLS stream in order to use the framework.

Answer (score 0):

**For live streaming using Azure framework I was getting 'SmoothStreaming' url.

Which I could not play on iOS device directly.As told by **Mingfei Yan in above answer****

So, We searched another way then Azure

- We followed this link to set up the IIS server.
  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=86968cd5-feeb-47f2-b02e-1eb4fa556379#commentstart
- And we got the Apple HLS stream to play in **Safari or
  WebView(iOS)**.

Still I am waiting to use Azure Frameork If I configure it properly.